# Indentation in footnotes when using \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

Tags: footnotes, indentation, footmisc

I am using `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}` so that all the text will be **right** of the footnote number. But this also prevents indents in footnotes alltogether.

When writing normal text, I usually get an indentation right away.

```
First paragraph.

Second paragraph.
```

results in

```
First paragraph.
   Second paragraph.
```

I would like to have this within footnotes, too. The options of `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}`, however, should still be valid.

---

**Minimum working example:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\addto\captionsbritish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of contents}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Titlepage \par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{One}
    Text.\footnote{This is a very long text. The sentences in this text are so long that they will cause a line break at the end of some sentences.\\Now, beginning a second paragraph with \texttt{\textbackslash\textbackslash} does not result in an indent of the second paragraph itself. Using a blank line between the two will just add some whitespace between the two paragraphs. But it will still not indent the second paragraph.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Does `\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0ex}\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{1em}` do what you want?

Comment: @DavidPurton No, it, unfortunately, doesn’t. I will provide a minimum working example as samcarter suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand something, but I think my first comment does solve your problem.

Your mistake is that new paragraphs in footnotes (as elsewhere) should be separated with a blank line, not `\\`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0ex}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{1em}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\null
\vfill
Filler text.\footnote{This is a very long text. The sentences in this text are
  so long that they will cause a line break at the end of some sentences.

  Now, beginning a second paragraph with a \textbf{blank line} does result in
an indent of the second paragraph itself.}

Filler text.\footnote{Another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not it works. I think I had a typo in my code when trying to add your commands.